# SparseIntArray lookup performance

Tags: android

I have access to both the key and the index of the value, I'd like to get from a `SparseIntArray`.

This means I can get the value with either `get(key)` or `valueAt(index)`.

I believe the latter would be **O(1)** complexity, but I'm not sure and I have no idea about the complexity of `get(key)`.

Which one is faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, let's check out the source code of the both implementations:

**get(key)**:

```
/**
 * Gets the int mapped from the specified key, or <code>0</code>
 * if no such mapping has been made.
 */
public int get(int key) {
    return get(key, 0);
}

/**
 * Gets the int mapped from the specified key, or the specified value
 * if no such mapping has been made.
 */
public int get(int key, int valueIfKeyNotFound) {
    int i = ContainerHelpers.binarySearch(mKeys, mSize, key);

    if (i < 0) {
        return valueIfKeyNotFound;
    } else {
        return mValues[i];
    }
}
```

**valueAt(index):**

```
/**
 * Given an index in the range <code>0...size()-1</code>, returns
 * the value from the <code>index</code>th key-value mapping that this
 * SparseIntArray stores.
 *
 * <p>The values corresponding to indices in ascending order are guaranteed
 * to be associated with keys in ascending order, e.g.,
 * <code>valueAt(0)</code> will return the value associated with the
 * smallest key and <code>valueAt(size()-1)</code> will return the value
 * associated with the largest key.</p>
 */
public int valueAt(int index) {
    return mValues[index];
}
```

Here the `get()` function first searches for the key and returns the value for the key, whereas the `valueAt()` function directly returns the value for the given index.

So, clearly `valueAt()` is faster than `get()`.

Answer (score 1):

From the Docs:

**valueAt() method:**

```
   public int valueAt(int index) {
        return mValues[index];
   }
```

**get() method:**

```
    public int get(int key) {
        return get(key, 0);
    }

    public int get(int key, int valueIfKeyNotFound) {
        int i = ContainerHelpers.binarySearch(mKeys, mSize, key);

        if (i < 0) {
          return valueIfKeyNotFound;
        } else {
          return mValues[i];
      }
    }
```

As you can see the above method **faster** method is `valueAt(key)` but it's not safe. It may produce you an `IndexOutOfBoundException`. But get(key) method will return you 0 if not such index found.